# Why rails 4 development and production environment behaves totally different, even with the same config?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, development-environment, production-environment

I'm developing a rails 4 application with ruby 2.0.0. Using the default application (just right after `rails new ...` ) switching between `rails s` (or `rails s -e development`) and `rails s -e production` the development version works fine and production version alerts an error:

```
No route matches [GET] "/"
Rails.root: /var/lib/stickshift/5239e9de500446eae7000028/app-root/data/584830
```

I already changed the `config/production.rb`:

```
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.serve_static_assets = true
  config.assets.compile = true
  config.assets.digest = true
```

This didn't work.

Then I just copied the `config/development.rb` to `config/production.rb` and started `rails s -e production` and so with equal config the development version works fine, but production still returns the same error.

What could be **so different** in production and development environments?

## Update:

I did all steps from this tutorial and still - no static files are available to serve
[https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4]

Answer (score 0):

I think the only thing that makes that difference is that rails doesn't add a default "Hello world" root in production. And that's not in the configs. That's why it gives an error, saying that you don't have a root route.

Comment: strange is that in development environment all the static files are served and in production environment they are not served

Comment: hm..never had that problem. If I set the confir properly, static assets show as needed.

Comment: Tried just now - everything's fine if you set  `config.serve_static_assets = true` and `config.assets.compile = true` (or run `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`).